# Query with sum in relation using Typeorm

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I'm studying some queries using Typeorm, but I'm having difficulties in performing the sum on a related table.

I have the following entities:

**Products**

```
@Entity('products')
class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id?: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column({ name: 'category_id' })
  categoryId: number;

  @Column()
  coast: number;

  @Column()
  price: number;

  @Column()
  type: string;

  @Column({ name: 'moves_stock' })
  movesStock: boolean;

  @Column({ name: 'to_sale' })
  toSale: boolean;

  @Column()
  observations: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => ProductCategory)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'category_id' })
  category: ProductCategory;

  @OneToMany(() => ProductPicture, picture => picture.product)
  pictures: ProductPicture[];

  @OneToMany(() => InventoryMoviment, inventory => inventory.material)
  inventory: InventoryMoviment[];

  @OneToMany(() => ProductComposition, composition => composition.product, {
    cascade: ['insert'],
  })
  composition: ProductComposition[];

  stock: number;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deleted_at?: Date;

  constructor() {
    if (!this.id) {
      this.id = uuid();
    }
  }
}
```

**Inventory Moviment**

```
@Entity('inventory_moviment')
class InventoryMoviment {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id?: number;

  @Column({ name: 'material_id' })
  materialId: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Product)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'material_id' })
  material: Product;

  @Column({ name: 'sale_id' })
  saleId?: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Sale)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'sale_id' })
  sale: Sale;

  @ManyToOne(() => Purchase)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'purchase_id' })
  purchase: Purchase;

  @Column({ name: 'purchase_id' })
  purchaseId?: string;

  @Column()
  type: string;

  @Column()
  quantity: number;

  @Column()
  coast: number;

  @Column()
  history?: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;
}
```

I have a query where with some filters and I need that when searching the products get the sum of the 'quantity' column for the returned products.

```
async listProductsByFilter({name,categoryId,toSale,types,}: IFilter):Promise<Product[]> {
const productsQuery = this.repository
  .createQueryBuilder('p')
  .leftJoin('inventory', 'i')
  .addSelect('SUM(i.quantity)', 'stock');

if (name) {
  productsQuery.andWhere('p.name like :nameL', {
    nameL: `%${name}%`,
  });
}

if (categoryId) {
  productsQuery.andWhere('p.category_id = :category', {
    category: categoryId,
  });
}

if (toSale !== undefined) {
  productsQuery.andWhere('p.to_sale = :toSale', { toSale });
}

if (types) {
  productsQuery.andWhere('p.type IN(:...types)', { types });
}

const produtcts = await productsQuery.getRawMany();

return produtcts;}
```

When I run this query I get the following error:

> 2022-06-10 11:17:52.322 UTC [54] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE" at character 493
> 2022-06-10 11:17:52.322 UTC [54] STATEMENT:  SELECT "p"."id" AS "p_id", "p"."name" AS "p_name", "p"."description" AS "p_description", "p"."category_id" AS "p_category_id", "p"."coast" AS "p_coast", "p"."price" AS "p_price", "p"."type" AS "p_type", "p"."moves_stock" AS "p_moves_stock", "p"."to_sale" AS "p_to_sale", "p"."observations" AS "p_observations", "p"."created_at" AS "p_created_at", "p"."updated_at" AS "p_updated_at", "p"."deleted_at" AS "p_deleted_at", SUM(i.quantity) AS "stock" FROM "products" "p" LEFT JOIN "inventory" "i" WHERE "p"."deleted_at" IS NULL

Comment: Change your `.leftJoin('inventory', 'i')` to `.leftJoin('p.inventory', 'i')` or `.innerJoin('p.inventory', 'i')`

Comment: Thank you. 
You are right.
Sorry for my carelessness